# Substituting everything from = to end of the line in VIM

Tags: vim, replace, substitution

Let's say I have several lines like:

```
$repeat_on =  $_REQUEST['repeat_on'];    
$opt_days = $_REQUEST['opt_day'];  
$opt_days = explode(",", $opt_days);
```

... and so on.

Let's say I use visual mode to select all the lines: how can I replace everything from `=` to the end of the line so it looks like:

```
$repeat_on = NULL;    
$opt_days =  NULL;
$opt_days =  NULL;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the block selected, use this substitute:

```
s/=.*$/= NULL;
```

The substitution regex changes each line by replacing anything between `=` and the end of the line, including the `=`, with `= NULL;`.

The first part of the command is the regex matching what is to be replaced: `=.*$`.

- The `=` is taken literally.
- The dot `.` means *any character*.
- So `.*` means: *0 or more of any character*.
- This is terminated by `$` for *end of line*, but this actually isn't necessary here: try it also without the `$`.

So the regex will match the region after the first `=` in each line, and replace that region with the replacement, which is `= NULL;`. We need to include the `=` in the replacement to add it back, since it's part of the match to be replaced.

When you have a block selected, and you hit `:` to enter a command, the command line will be automatically prefixed with a range for the visual selection that looks like this:

```
:'<,'>
```

Continue typing the command above, and your command-line will be:

```
:'<,'>s/=.*$/= NULL;
```

Which will apply the replacement to the selected visual block.

If you'll need to have multiple replacements on a single line, you'll need to add the `g` flag:

```
:'<,'>s/=.*$/= NULL;/g
```

Comment: Dope thanks. Can you explain the actual reg pattern and how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives:

### Visual Block (fast)

On the first line/character do... `Wl<C-v>jjCNULL;<Esc>bi<Space><Esc>`

### Macro (faster)

On the first line/character do... `qqWllCNULL;<esc>+q2@q`

### :norm (fastest)

On the first line do... `3:no<S-tab> WllCNULL;<Enter>`

Or if you've visually selected the lines leave the 3 off the beginning.